# Powershell Aggregate Nested Array Values

Tags: powershell

How do I get the Average column to collect into an average?

The closest thing I have is:

```
$metric_result | Format-Table -Property @{label='Name';e={$_.Name.Value}},Unit,@{label='Average';e={$_.Data.Average}}

Name                               Unit Average
----                               ---- ---
Percentage CPU                  Percent {$null, $null, $null, $null…}
Disk Read Operations/Sec CountPerSecond {$null, $null, $null, $null…}
```

I'd like to get a final output that looks like:

```
Name                               Unit Average
----                               ---- ----
Percentage CPU                  Percent 0.234
Disk Read Operations/Sec CountPerSecond 0.043
```

I have a powershell System.Array, `$metric_result`, that looks like this:

```
Id         : /my/special/id
Name       :
                LocalizedValue : Percentage CPU
                Value          : Percentage CPU

Type       : Microsoft.Insights/metrics
Unit       : Percent
Data       : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue…}
Timeseries : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.TimeSeriesElement}

Id         : /my/special/id2
Name       :
                LocalizedValue : Disk Read Operations/Sec
                Value          : Disk Read Operations/Sec

Type       : Microsoft.Insights/metrics
Unit       : CountPerSecond
Data       : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue…}
Timeseries : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.TimeSeriesElement}
```

The `$metric_result.Data` field is a collection of values that looks like:

```
TimeStamp : 7/30/2019 11:39:00 PM
Average   : 0.292142857142857
Minimum   :
Maximum   :
Total     :
Count     :
```

Comment: Can you please share the ouput of `$metric_result.Data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$metric_result | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID      = $_.ID
        Name    = $_.Name.LocalizedValue
        Unit    = $_.Unit
        Average = "{0:N3}" -f ($_.Data.Average|Measure -Ave).Average 
    }
}
```

Comment: Data is a collection of objects that have a property of Average. The intent is to find the average of that value. Confusing I know. Too many things called Average

Answer (score 1):

After trying some of the previous answers and reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) about creating calculated properties for each InputObject, this is what I got to work

```
$average = @{l="Average";e={($_.Data.Average | Measure-Object -Average).Average}}
$local_name = @{l='Name';e={$_.Name.LocalizedValue}}

$metric_result | Select-Object -Property $local_name,Unit,$average


Name                               Unit Average
----                               ---- ----
Percentage CPU                  Percent 0.234
Disk Read Operations/Sec CountPerSecond 0.043
```

Comment: Quite some changes from your question, switch to LocalizedValue, added ID. I'm curious if my changed answer yields the same result.

Comment: That's true, I'll update to the original simplified question